# awk - get least count where key appears minimum time

Tags: awk

I'm trying to get key and its occurrence value where it is minimum among other key occurrences.

Below is the input

```
$ cat  in1.txt
102,27.40
102,35.40
102,23.40
102,57.40
103,56.40
103,23.76
103,12.50
103,87.12
103,52.90
103,35.70
103,72.80
106,56.12
106,66.43
105,87.12
105,34.90
105,55.00
```

I tried something like below to get the max occurrence and it gives correct results.

```
$ awk -F, ' { c[$1]++;if(max<c[$1]) { max=c[$1];maxa=$1 }} END { print max, maxa } ' in1.txt
7 103
```

that is key=103 occurs 7 times where 7 is the maximum compared to other key occurrences of 102=4, 106=2 and 105=3

Similarly, I want to get the minimum, but it is giving incorrect results

```
$ awk -F, ' { if(NR==1) { min=1;minr=$1 } c[$1]++;if(c[$1]<=min ) { min=c[$1];minr=$1 }} END { print min, minr } '  in1.txt
1 105  # Wrong
```

The expected result is

```
2 106
```

Could you please help in fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is organized with all key values contiguous as shown in your sample input then you can do this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
$1 != prev {
    if ( NR == 1 ) {
        minKey = $1
        maxKey = $1
    }
    else {
        minKey = (cnt[prev] <= cnt[minKey] ? prev : minKey)
        maxKey = (cnt[prev] >= cnt[maxKey] ? prev : maxKey)
    }
    prev = $1
}
{ cnt[$1]++ }
END {
    minKey = (cnt[prev] <= cnt[minKey] ? prev : minKey)
    maxKey = (cnt[prev] >= cnt[maxKey] ? prev : maxKey)
    print cnt[minKey], minKey
    print cnt[maxKey], maxKey
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2 106
7 103
```

If not then you can always do `sort file | awk -f tst.awk` to make them so before awk sees them.

Comment: thanks Ed, this is what I was looking for.. I can manage the input to be sorted..

Answer (score 3):

this will do both

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1]++; min++} 
        END{for(k in a) 
             {if(a[k]<min) {min=a[k]; mink=k} 
              if(a[k]>max) {max=a[k]; maxk=k}} 
              print "min",min,mink; 
              print "max",max,maxk}' file 

min 2 106
max 7 103
```

or perhaps complete counts, easier

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1]++} END{for(k in a) print a[k],k}' file | sort -n

2 106
3 105
4 102
7 103
```

first script counts all lines to set a default value for min, the max won't need one.

Or, without `awk`

```
$ cut -d, -f1 file | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

2 106
3 105
4 102
7 103
```

head/tail will give you the min and max correspondingly.

Comment: thank you for the solution.. I'm still trying to understand if there is way to do the comparison in the main section just like I tried for max in my solution?.

Comment: you can, I don't think it will be faster though.  For your script you need to set the min to a (very) high number so that it can be updated.  By setting it to one, you guarantee that it won't be updated if you compared with `<`, since you compare with `<=` it will be updated after each key's first appearance.